# About Correct or Wrong answer

Tags: android, android-studio

I want a test for 3-4 years old childs. I want if they click different apple , true count must plus one. And if they click one of same aplles false count must plus one. And click any apple the question and apples are must change.

My friend helped me and we did much of them. On clicks question and answers changing. But when click any apple wrong count plus one no matter it's true or false answer.

Can u pls help me?

We think we only have problems on if commands. He tried on it so much but couldn't solve the problem.

class file:

```js
package tr.com.blogspot.etkinlikhavuzu.benimilkogretmenim;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by erisk on 31.01.2017.
 */

public class AA extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView soru,dogrusayi,yanlissayi;
    ImageView secenek1,secenek2,secenek3;
    ArrayList<Soru> sorular;
    Random random;
    int dogruSayisi,yanlisSayisi,sayac,dogruCevap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.aa);

        init();

        sorulariYukle();
    }

    public void init(){
        secenek1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secenek1);
        secenek1.setOnClickListener(this);
        secenek2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secenek2);
        secenek2.setOnClickListener(this);
        secenek3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secenek3);
        secenek3.setOnClickListener(this);

        soru = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soru);
        dogrusayi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dogrusayi);
        yanlissayi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yanlissayi);

        sorular = new ArrayList<Soru>();

        random = new Random();
    }

    public void sorulariYukle(){
        sorular.add(new Soru("Hangi Elma Yeşildir?",R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.yesilelma));
        sorular.add(new Soru("Hangi Elma Kırmızıdır?",R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.kirmizielma));
        sorular.add(new Soru("Hangi Elma Yeşildir?",R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.yesilelma));
        sorular.add(new Soru("Hangi Elma Kırmızıdır?",R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.kirmizielma));
        sorular.add(new Soru("Hangi Elma Yeşildir?",R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.kirmizielma,R.drawable.yesilelma,R.drawable.yesilelma));

        sayac = random.nextInt(5);

        soru.setText(sorular.get(sayac).getSoru());
        secenek1.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek1());
        secenek2.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek2());
        secenek3.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek3());
        dogruCevap = sorular.get(sayac).getDogruCevap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.secenek1:
                if(secenek1.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(dogruCevap)){
                    dogruSayisi++;
                    dogrusayi.setText(String.valueOf(dogruSayisi));
                }else{
                    yanlisSayisi++;
                    yanlissayi.setText(String.valueOf(yanlisSayisi));
                }
                sayac = random.nextInt(5);
                soru.setText(sorular.get(sayac).getSoru());
                secenek1.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek1());
                secenek2.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek2());
                secenek3.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek3());
                dogruCevap = sorular.get(sayac).getDogruCevap();
                break;
            case R.id.secenek2:
                if(secenek2.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(dogruCevap)){
                    dogruSayisi++;
                    dogrusayi.setText(String.valueOf(dogruSayisi));
                }else{
                    yanlisSayisi++;
                    yanlissayi.setText(String.valueOf(yanlisSayisi));
                }
                sayac = random.nextInt(5);
                soru.setText(sorular.get(sayac).getSoru());
                secenek1.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek1());
                secenek2.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek2());
                secenek3.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek3());
                dogruCevap = sorular.get(sayac).getDogruCevap();
                break;
            case R.id.secenek3:
                if(secenek3.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(dogruCevap)){
                    dogruSayisi++;
                    dogrusayi.setText(String.valueOf(dogruSayisi));
                }else{
                    yanlisSayisi++;
                    yanlissayi.setText(String.valueOf(yanlisSayisi));
                }
                sayac = random.nextInt(5);
                soru.setText(sorular.get(sayac).getSoru());
                secenek1.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek1());
                secenek2.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek2());
                secenek3.setImageResource(sorular.get(sayac).getSecenek3());
                dogruCevap = sorular.get(sayac).getDogruCevap();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

xml file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="tr.com.blogspot.etkinlikhavuzu.benimilkogretmenim.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogru"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/dogru" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yanlis"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dogru"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yanlis" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dogrusayi"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/yanlis"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dogru"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dogru"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dogrusayi"
            android:textColor="#006600"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yanlissayi"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yanlis"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/yanlis"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yanlis"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/yanlissayi"
            android:textColor="#990000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/secenek1"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/secenek2"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/secenek1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/secenek3"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/secenek2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/soru"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/secenek2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dogrusayi"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dogrusayi"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hangi Elma Yeşildir?"
            android:textColor="#006600"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/siradaki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="1" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And Soru.class file

```js
package tr.com.blogspot.etkinlikhavuzu.benimilkogretmenim;

/**
 * Created by erisk on 31.01.2017.
 */

public class Soru {
    String soru;
    int secenek1,secenek2,secenek3,dogruCevap;

    public Soru(String soru, int secenek1, int secenek2, int secenek3, int dogruCevap) {
        this.soru = soru;
        this.secenek1 = secenek1;
        this.secenek2 = secenek2;
        this.secenek3 = secenek3;
        this.dogruCevap = dogruCevap;
    }

    public String getSoru() {
        return soru;
    }

    public void setSoru(String soru) {
        this.soru = soru;
    }

    public int getSecenek1() {
        return secenek1;
    }

    public void setSecenek1(int secenek1) {
        this.secenek1 = secenek1;
    }

    public int getSecenek2() {
        return secenek2;
    }

    public void setSecenek2(int secenek2) {
        this.secenek2 = secenek2;
    }

    public int getSecenek3() {
        return secenek3;
    }

    public void setSecenek3(int secenek3) {
        this.secenek3 = secenek3;
    }

    public int getDogruCevap() {
        return dogruCevap;
    }

    public void setDogruCevap(int dogruCevap) {
        this.dogruCevap = dogruCevap;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: my opinion:
Integer correct = 0; Integer wrong = 0; String last_chosen = ""; 
every time chose in not last_chosen correct = correct +1; 
every time chose is last_chosen = wrong = wrong +1;
then collect all answer as want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing drawables. which never matches.
Change your if(CONDITION) to following:

```
if(secenek1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(dogruCevap).getConstantState())).
```

same way for other two cases.